# REGEX two decimals required

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

I have a regex `^\d+(\.\d{2})?$`

Here, the two decimals are optional. I want the decimals to be mandatory. Any suggestions?

Comment: actually **?** at the end is your culprit..Just shift it to a prison and you got your task sized down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `?` at the end. And the grouping is then also not needed.

```
^\d+\.\d{2}$
```

[see msdn about quantifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#quantifiers)

Comment: You could also specify the role of the grouping in the original expression (ie, that it makes its inner regex an atom wrt quantifiers)